# Java String to Date Parse

Tags: java

I am trying convert String to Date but getting this error.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 16 20:04:17 EET 2022"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
at com.mycompany.facebookproject.OpenFace.main(OpenFace.java:55)
```

My code is:

```
String val= "Wed Feb 16 20:04:19 EET 2022";
expiry=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(val);
```

Comment: Your code works, check this out: https://repl.it/repls/BlondChartreuseSlope

Comment: What is `val` in `parse()`?

Comment: The important part of the duplicate is: *Note the importance of the explicit `Locale` argument. If you omit it, then it will use the default locale which is not necessarily English as used in the month name of the input string. If the locale doesn't match with the input string, then you would confusingly get a `java.text.ParseException` even though when the format pattern seems valid.* --- To fix, add `Locale.US` as second parameter to `SimpleDateFormat` constructor.

Comment: Its EET for which I guess locale should be different

Comment: @DhrubajyotiGogoi No, it's `Wed`. And `Feb`. And `EET`, so you're partially correct. E.g. in German, that text input would be `Mi. Feb. 16 20:04:19 OEZ 2022`, and in French it would be `mer. févr. 16 20:04:19 EET 2022`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess its a typo:

```
String dateSt= "Wed Feb 16 20:04:19 EET 2022";
        Date parse = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(dateSt);
        System.out.println(parse);
```

Comment: That is not an answer, but a relevant point, though.

Comment: Yes this is not an answer but thank you :)

Comment: Be sure to set correct Locale

Comment: Now [that comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60268233/java-string-to-date-parse#comment106605076_60268288) would be the correct answer. But, already covered in answer to another question, so this question has been closed.

Comment: Yes I added Locale.CANADA and problem fixed. Thank you again

Comment: @Andreas made valid points but just to add java.util.Date does not contain timezone information. In case to you timezoned datetimes use ZonedDateTime instead